# Cleanest way to deserialize a non-standard (wrong) format of list of JSON string that doesn't have quote

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I'm trying to deserialize a Java `String` to a `List` of `String`. Due to some reason, the input may come in two formats:

```
"[\"string1\", \"string2\"]"
```

or

```
"[string1, string2]"
```

The library I'm using is Jackson databind.

For the first case, it's a typical, easy case that Jackson supports.

For the second, I understand it's not a correct format of JSON and I can hack to achieve the goal by splitting this `String` by `,` and remove `[]`s etc, but just would like to know if someone knows a clean way to deserialize something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you can look into [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Basic_components) parsers. :)
Jackson has an [extention](https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson) for YAML support so that would be your clean solution.
YAML is a superset of JSON so it can parse any valid JSON... as well as many more complex transcripts (like strings without `"`).